# Find Listview clicked section adapter in mergeadapter?

Tags: android, android-listview, commonsware-cwac

I am using merge adapter to merge two custom cursor adapters in android.I could not find clicked section to get data from my custom cursor adapter.How can I get adapter object when listview clicked?. 
I tried following way in my onitemclick of listview. But it does not print "clicked on mention question section" text.But it returns android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@41b9a638.How can I find which section is clicked in listview?

```
if (parent.getAdapter().getItem(position) instanceof FeedMentionQuestionAdapter) {
        LivLog.info(getClass(), "clicked on mention question section  ");

    }
```

Comment: @CommonsWare,Please see my comment in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get adapter object when listview clicked?

You need to hold onto your own adapter, or call `getAdapter()` on your `ListView`.

> But it returns android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@41b9a638

Presumably, you put a `CursorAdapter` in the `MergeAdapter`.

Also, `getItem()` will never return an adapter. It returns items. If you are trying to determine the adapter that handles a particular `position`, call `getAdapter()`.

> How can I find which section is clicked in listview?

If you are referring to `SectionIndexer`, then sections are not clicked.

Comment: I tried following steps to find which section clicked on listview.But I could not find the section which I clicked.
   Step 1: mergeadapter.getAdapter(position) ->  but it returns "com.liv.network.adapter.FeedQuestionCursorAdapter@429867c0" as result.I used FeedQuestionCursorAdapter 
   as second part of merge adapter.It always returns "com.liv.network.adapter.FeedQuestionCursorAdapter@429867c0" , when I click on the first part of the mergeadapter
   .And first part of the mergeadapter is FeedMentionQuestionAdapter.

Comment: Step 2: if(lvFeedquestions.getAdapter() instanceof FeedMentionQuestionAdapter ){
   
   LivLog.info(getClass(), "mention stanza ");
   
     }else if(lvFeedquestions.getAdapter() instanceof FeedQuestionCursorAdapter){
    
     LivLog.info(getClass(), "general stanza ");
   
  }else{
   
   LivLog.info(getClass(), "something went wrong.....");   
  }

Comment: But it always returns "something went wrong....." as a log message.
  
  Please suggest , How can I solve this problm. I want to determine which adapter is clicked?

Comment: @BABUK: I have no idea.

Comment: Is there any other solution to find adapter view clicked?

Comment: @BABUK: I cannot make sense of the code that you pasted into the comments. I do not have any of the code where you are creating this `MergeAdapter`. I have no way to help you further at this point. If you feel that this is a possible bug in `MergeAdapter`, create a project that demonstrates the bug, and [file an issue](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge/issues?state=open) with a link to the project and steps for reproducing the problem.

Comment: ,I will do as you said.